# How to show all the tags related to a publication in a list of publications filtered by a tag in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many

## Consider following models:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    number_of_publications = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="publications")
```

```
# urls.py

from .views import publications_tagged
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('publications/tagged/<str:name>', publications_tagged)
]
```

```
# views.py

from .models import Tag, Publication
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render


def publications_tagged(request, name):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag.objects.prefetch_related('publications'), name=name)
    return render(request, 'myapp/tagged_questions.html', {'tag': tag})
```

Ok, so when we'd go to a template and make a for-loop that will create a representation of every publication and show appropriate tags of it, Django would make a database call for every publication to fetch all the tags the publication has, meaning:

Iteration `x` of `tag.publications` -> check what tags match with `publication X`.

Of course, we can just not show tags and everything will work like magic (utilizing `prefetch_related`), but that's not what we want :)

## **How could we do something similar in Django?**

What we want is some kind of optimized way to achieve such a result, because stackoverflow renders 15 items really fast, which makes me think they do not do it the monkey way that Django does by default.

[This is what html might look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXK3J.jpg)

[This is what html **code** might look like](https://pastebin.com/GtY3gmwF)

P.S. My problem doesn't quite sound like that. But just in case anyone would say: "Oh, it's a bad design, you shouldn't do that at all" I decided to show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really simple, all you have to do is in the `prefetch_related` specify `publications__tags`, which leaves you with:

```
tag = get_object_or_404(Tag.objects.prefetch_related('publications', 'publications__tags'), name=name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property to your `Publication` model to render `tags` as a list of strings, so:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    @property
    def tags_list(self):
        # renders as ["django", "python", ...]
        return list(self.tags.values_list("name", flat=True))
```

> Make sure you use `prefetch_related("tags")` to optimize your query.

**Update I:**

To suit your view code you'll use `prefetch_related` as:

```
from .models import Tag, Publication
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render


def publications_tagged(request, name):
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag.objects.prefetch_related('publications', 'publications__tags'), name=name)
    return render(request, 'myapp/tagged_questions.html', {'tag': tag})
```

**Update II:**

You can read more about `prefetch_related` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. [django_toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) shows that I still have a query for every publication _(e.g. for 2 publications, I'll have a query for the tag, another for related publications, and for every publications a query to get all the related tags to it, which makes it 4 queries_, in other words: O(2+n)=O(n). So for the site like stackoverflow (with 15 items for a page) a request to a page would produce 17 queries - **is there a better way?**
P.S I'm not quite sure where to put this `prefetch_related` as it works only with querysets.

Comment: Nevertheless, your solution works faster